# Octave - return the position of the first occurrence of a string in a cell array

Tags: string, matlab, octave, string-search

Is there a function in Octave that returns the position of the first occurrence of a string in a cell array?

I found `findstr` but this returns a vector, which I do not want. I want what `index` does but it only works for strings.

If there is no such function, are there any tips on how to go about it?

Comment: Do you want the first occurrence in each cell or for the entire cell array?

Comment: Reopened from the duplicate because this question is asking to find the **first occurrence** of the string, not **all occurrences**.  The accepted answer also handles the nuance of not being able to find the string. 
 This question has a fundamental difference which leads to a different solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [`findstr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Manipulating-Strings.html#XREFfindstr) is being deprecated, a combination of [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Finding-Elements-and-Checking-Conditions.html#XREFfind) and [`strcmpi`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Comparing-Strings.html#XREFstrcmpi) may prove useful.  `strcmpi` compares strings by ignoring the case of the letters which may be useful for your purposes. If this is not what you want, use the function without the trailing `i`, so [`strcmp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Comparing-Strings.html#XREFstrcmp).  The input into `strcmpi` or `strcmp` are the string to search for `str` and for your case the additional input parameter is a cell array `A` of strings to search in. The output of `strcmpi` or `strcmp` will give you a vector of `logical` values where each location `k` tells you whether the string `k` in the cell array `A` matched with `str`.  You would then use `find` to find all locations of where the string matched, but you can further restrain it by specifying the maximum number of locations `n` as well as where to constrain your search - specifically if you want to look at the first or last `n` locations where the string matched.

If the desired string is in `str` and your cell array is stored in `A`, simply do:

```
index = find(strcmpi(str, A)), 1, 'first');
```

To reiterate, `find` will find all locations where the string matched, while the second and third parameters tell you to only return the first index of the result.  Specifically, this will return the first occurrence of the desired searched string, or the empty array if it can't be found.

## Example Run

```
octave:8> A = {'hello', 'hello', 'how', 'how', 'are', 'you'};
octave:9> str = 'hello';
octave:10> index = find(strcmpi(str, A), 1, 'first')
index =  1
octave:11> str = 'goodbye';
octave:12> index = find(strcmpi(str, A), 1, 'first')
index = [](1x0)
```

Comment: Worth noting that `strcmp`/`strcmpi` only compares *full* strings, so if you're searching for the existence substring you'll probably need to use a regex.

Comment: @excaza Good comment. I assumed the OP wanted to search for the full string.  The language suggests so, but my assumptions have bitten me in the @$$ before.

Comment: @rayryeng This is perfect! Thank you. And you're assumption was right, I wanted to search for the full string.

Comment: @CH123 Ah very nice, then the above code will be very suitable for your purposes.  Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng, Thank you for your nice answer. However I couldn't find any comment of [excaza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2748311/excaza) above your answer. May be it is deleted. Would you mind editing your answer accordingly?

Comment: @Md.AbuNafeeIbnaZahid it was a comment and I unfortunately can't remember what he said.